# How to get the unique ID of a job with GearmanBundle

Tags: php, symfony, gearman, symfony-2.4

I'm attempting to use [Gearman Bundle](https://github.com/mmoreram/GearmanBundle) but can't see how to access unique job IDs rather than job handles

```
$gmClient = $this->get('gearman');

$gmClient->addServer('127.0.0.1', 4730);

$result = $gmClient->doBackgroundJob("ShareightBundleAdminBundleWorkersGetImageSizeWorker~getImageSizes",
    'test','myuniqueid'); //this returns the job handle

$this->jobHandle = $result;
$jobStatus = $gmClient->getJobStatus($result);
var_dump($jobStatus);exit;
```

There is a config parameter for the bundle - `generate_unique_key: true` - but I can't see anywhere in the docs how to make use of this generated key

Answer (score 0):

Unique ids are used for coalescing jobs and not intended to identify an individual job. Gearman therefore does not provide a method to get job status by unique id and neither does the bundle in question. The job handle is the only valid parameter for retrieving job status.